# ReactJS: Make a table editable using react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react-table npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) for generating my table:

```
<ReactTable
    data={ tableData }
    columns={ tableColumns }
    showPagination={ false }
    defaultPageSize={ tableData.length }
/>
```

The table is shown as expected. But now I would like to make this table editable. So I need to use input fields with data value instead of just text data values.

How do I have to do that? I do not understand the docs for this point... So I need some help.

Comment: If I understand it, <ReactTable> is available in v6 but not v7, which is "headless"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to edit the Columns props

```
Check render: props => <input value={props.row.name} onChange={onChangeFct} />
```

For example:

```
const onChangeFct = () => console.log("onChange usually handled by redux");
const tableColumns = [
{
    header: 'Id',
    accessor: 'id'
},
{
    header: 'Name',
    accessor: 'name',
    render: props => <input value={props.row.name} onChange={onChangeFct} />
}
]


<ReactTable
    data={ tableData }
    columns={ tableColumns }
    showPagination={ false }
    defaultPageSize={ tableData.length }
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use text in place edit plugins like [react-x-editable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-x-editable) plugin to make table editable as it provides both modes: inline and popup.